# Build maven project within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

I have a java project (actually it is just a wrapper for some corporate JAR files) that I would like to build using maven, in Eclipse.

Meaning, whenever the working space is being built, a maven build should be executed for this particular project.

I added a Maven Project Builder in the list of builders of that project:
[image]

No problems are detected, although, when building the work space, the following error is raised:
[image]

I am able to create a Run Configuration, and when executed, the project is built properly. But I would like an option that just build the project along with the rest of the work space...

Is there a way of achieving this?

(Not sure if this is relevant but here is the Maven Lifecycle Mapping for the project:)
[image]

Comment: get a help from this url: http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-new-simple-maven-project-in-eclipse-without-archtype-detailed-steps-included/

Comment: @ArifMustafa Thanks! I suppose that would be ok if my project was only maven, bu it actually is a eclipse RCP plugin so it must contain the MANIFEST.MF to be exported with the correct OSGi info....

Comment: Since project builds are triggered by any number of possible modifications, builders are usually incremental. Are you certain you wish to trigger a full maven build for every slight change in the project?

Comment: Well, probably is not the best approach... but at least I would like to know how to do it :p Do you know how to do it? If at the end it doesn't fit my needs, will search for a different approach...

Comment: Try tycho maven plugin